# Javascript (Jquery), increment/decrement ++/-- operator calculates wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I am making a slideshow with two right and left buttons and when the buttons are clicked the images `src` changes and new image comes up. The location of the images are stored in an array and `++` operator are used to move the photo next and `--` for previous sometimes it does not work I have to double click the buttons to work. Why is this happening ?

---

HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <a href="" id="left"><img src="images/left.png" width="80px"    height="80px"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" id="image">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <a href="" id="right"><img src="images/right.png" width="80px"  height="80px"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
var count = 1;

        var imagesLocation = ['images/1.jpg',
                              'images/2.jpg',
                              'images/3.jpg',
                              'images/4.jpg',
                              'images/5.jpg'];

        $('#right').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if(count < 6){
                $('#image').attr('src',imagesLocation[count]);
                count++;
            }
        });

        $('#left').on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            count--;
            $('#image').attr('src',imagesLocation[count]);

        });
```

Comment: javascript array indetx starts at 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array index is starting from `0` not `1`

```js
var count = 0;
//----------^--- update here

var imagesLocation = ['images/1.jpg',
  'images/2.jpg',
  'images/3.jpg',
  'images/4.jpg',
  'images/5.jpg'
];

$('#right').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (count < imagesLocation.length) {
    //--------^----- .length can be use instead, so this will work even if array size changed
    $('#image').attr('src', imagesLocation[++count]);
    //-------------------------------------^--  ++count will increment the count, then returns the incremented count value    
  }
});

$('#left').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (count > 0) {
    //------^---- to avoid negative index    
    $('#image').attr('src', imagesLocation[--count]);
    //-------------------------------------^--  --count will decrements the count, then returns the decremented count value
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <a href="" id="left">
      <img src="images/left.png" width="80px" height="80px">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <img src="images/1.jpg" id="image">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1">
    <a href="" id="right">
      <img src="images/right.png" width="80px" height="80px">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: An additional issue is that with enough clicks on left, count can take up negative values, and it cannot be used as an array index until it's back up to 0.

Comment: Also why don't you suggest the use of `.length` property?

Comment: still I have to double click, since the count is set to 0

Comment: @amguruprasath : initially in your right button click `count` value is incremented after changing the image , that's why it's only changing image after the second click only

Answer (score 3):

Try This...

```
    var count = 0;

    var imagesLocation =      ['images/1.jpg','images/2.jpg','images/3.jpg','images/4.jpg','images/5.jpg'];

    $('#right').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (count < 5) {
    $('#image').attr('src', imagesLocation[count]);
     count++;
     }
    });

    $('#left').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      count--;
    $('#image').attr('src', imagesLocation[count]);

    });
```

Array index starts from 0...

Comment: Count is set to 1 because I have the image in the place 0 is already displayed if its set to zero again I have to double click